# How to expand entry box with window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just creating simple window using tkinter which have entry box and search button. What is want is when i maximize window search bar also starch but it is not happening,

Here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Wikipedia")

class first:
    def labels(self):
        search_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root)
        search_frame.pack(side = "top",fill = "both")
        
        search_var = tk.StringVar()
        search_bar = tk.Entry(search_frame,width = 40,textvariable = search_var)
        search_bar.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
        
        search_button = ttk.Button(search_frame,text = "Search")
        search_button.grid(row = 1,column = 0)
boot = first()
boot.labels()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `sticky="news"` in the `.grid` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Wikipedia")


class first:
    def labels(self):
        search_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root)
        search_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both")


        search_var = tk.StringVar()
        search_bar = tk.Entry(search_frame, width=20, textvariable=search_var)
        search_bar.pack(fill="x")

        search_button = ttk.Button(search_frame, text="Search")
        search_button.pack()


boot = first()
boot.labels()
root.mainloop()
```

Not sure this is what you're looking for but try it out.
Here I have used `fill='x'` in the `.pack()` geometry manager to fill the row